# error message: Object reference not set to an instance

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript code on my aspx clientside that is resulting in an error

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

on the following line:

```
var dateOfService = new Date(document.getElementById('<%= this.txtDOS.ClientID %>').value);
```

However, when I 'Add Watch' to `this.txtDOS.ClientID`, I get *ctl00_MainContent_txtDOS*

This occurs after the page is refreshed using a popup window aspx:panel control.
I have tried debugging, but not getting too far.

What would be causing the error?

Comment: Is txtDOS a dynamically added control?

Comment: What happens when you remove `this.` and just use `<%= txtDOS.ClientID %>`?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it is not dynamically added. The control is added at design time

Comment: @MikeSmithDev this code was working fine yesterday. Nothing happened between last night and now. :-) except for the error (so this should work fine)

Comment: @MikeSmithDev... tried without this... same error

Comment: Just a stupid question... :) Could it be that the NullReferenceException comes from a different place in the code?What is the stacktrace info? line of error?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev when I do an Add Watch on txtDOS.ClientID, I get the same value returned.

Comment: @Csharp then like Shai said, likely other source of error. If `txtDOS` isn't null... then something else is.

Comment: I have checked all fields, there are no nulls

Comment: are you enabling the viewstate in txtDOS textbox? to me it looks like you're losing the txt value during the postback, then by the time you try to create a new date with an empty parameter you got the null reference

Comment: but when I do Add Watch, txtDOS has a value...

Comment: viewstate is enabled on txtDOS.